# Is it possible to add another inbox in lotus notes 7 that already has an inbox

Tags: lotus-notes

Hi guyzz what i really want to is, is it really possible to add another inbox in lotus notes 7 that already has an inbox?What i mean is 2 inboxen in lotus notes. ahh yes i'm using lotus notes 7.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you really want.  Do you want multiple email accounts, with the messages to each address being delivered to a separate Inbox within your Notes client?  If so, are you asking about multiple email accounts that are all coming in through your organization's Lotus Domino mail servers?  Or are you asking about email accounts on servers outside of your organization, such as gmail, yahoo, etc?

Comment: Totally agree with rhsatrhs. The answer could be "Yes of course" or "No never" or "Maybe"... Don't get what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two "Inbox" folders as such, as it is a reserved folder and may lead to problems. Actually most issues I've seen is the customer trying to remove a second inbox.

That said, you can of course create another folder in the mail file and then create a mail rule to move an incoming mail to that folder based on certain criteria.

Although R8 documentation, it should still apply to what you want.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.notes.help.doc/DOC/H_USING_RULES_TO_FILTER_NEW_MESSAGES_STEPS.html